# How to observe more levels from realtime-database Firebase?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, nsmutablearray

My code do not add values from a `while` statement of a `UIViewController` to an Array of a `UITableViewController`.

This is for a getter function to allow me to see all childrens values under other childrens. Now I'm going to be more specific:

My database node is made of:

> Cars ->  0, 1, 2, 3, ...  -> Model, Price, ... -> String

As you can see, The number of childs is undefined, so I have to use this control method:

```
while let child = snapshotChildren.nextObject() as? DataSnapshot {
            // Get code node key and save it to cars array
        }
```

First of all, In a loading `ViewController`, I get code node keys of cars and save them to cars variable of type `NSMutableArray` of the `TableViewController`. Then I will do the same thing in the `TableViewController` to get all `indexpath.row` childrens value.

```
let rootRef = Database.database().reference()
    let carconditionalRef = rootRef.child("Cars")
    carconditionalRef.observe(.value) {(snap: DataSnapshot) in
//Get all the children from snapshot you got back from Firebase
    let snapshotChildren = snap.children
//Loop over all children (code) in Firebase
        while let child = snapshotChildren.nextObject() as? DataSnapshot {
                  // Get code node key and save it to cars array
                     let carvc = Cars_Table();
                     carvc.cars.add(child.key)
             }
         }
```

It results that with this code I still have empty `NSMutableArray`. How can I solve this?

**Edit 1**

---

<del>I fixed</del> that snippet to this:

```
import UIKit
import FirebaseDatabase

class Loading: UIViewController {


    @IBOutlet weak var loading: UIActivityIndicatorView!

    var mother: NSMutableArray = []

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        start()
    }

    func start() {

        loading.startAnimating()
        if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
            Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 0.1, repeats: false) { (timer) in

                //let's dance
                self.loading.startAnimating()

                //call data from database
                let rootRef = Database.database().reference()
                let conditionalRef = rootRef.child("Cars")
                conditionalRef.observe(.value) {(snap: DataSnapshot) in
                    // Get all the children from snapshot you got back from Firebase
                    let snapshotChildren = snap.children
                    // Loop over all children (code) in Firebase
                    while let child = snapshotChildren.nextObject() as? DataSnapshot {
                        // Get code node key and save it to cars array
                        self.mother.add(child.key)
                    }

                    self.move()
                    self.loading.stopAnimating()
                    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "loadingfinish", sender: nil)



                }
            }
        } else {
            // Fallback on earlier versions
        }

    }

    func move() {

    let vc = Cars_Table()
        vc.cars = self.mother

    }

}
```

**Edit 2**

---

I tried using the recursive method, but it did not work. So I tried one more time with the iterative method this time using the `while` statement.

Here my new function, this time directly in the `Car_TableView.swift`:

```
func loadData() {
    //call data from database
    let rootRef = Database.database().reference()
    let conditionalRef = rootRef.child("Cars")
    conditionalRef.observe(.value) {(snap: DataSnapshot) in
        // Get all the children from snapshot you got back from Firebase
        let snapshotChildren = snap.children
        // Loop over all children (code) in Firebase

        while let child = snapshotChildren.nextObject() as? DataSnapshot {
            // Get code node key and save it to cars array
            self.populateTable.append(child.key)
        }

        var counter = 0

        while counter > -self.populateTable.count {
            counter -= 1

            let rootRef = Database.database().reference()

                let userRef = rootRef.child("Cars").child("\(self.populateTable.count+counter)")

                userRef.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in
                    let userDict = snapshot.value as! [String: Any]

                        let model1 = userDict["Model"] as! String
                        self.model.add(model1)

                        let detail1 = userDict["Detail"] as! String
                        self.detailpage.add(detail1)

                        let year1 = userDict["Year"] as! String
                        self.year.add(year1)

                        let carPrice1 = userDict["Price"]  as! String
                        self.price.add(carPrice1)

                        let carimageURL1 = userDict["imageURL"]  as! String
                        self.imagePathString.add(carimageURL1)
                }) //end observeSingleEvent



        }

        }
  }
```

When I go to do the `while`, the `observeSingleEvent` will be work, but it will repeat n^2 times. Why does this happen?

**Edit 3**

---

Since the problem seems to be changed since the start, I edited to give all the relevant details. So, the problem now is different and now are two:

1. When I load database I have n^2 repeated instruction
2. To see the table filled with database data, I have to touch the tab bar button to the next `ViewController` then touch the tab bar button to come back on `Car_TableView.swift`

For the first problem... onestly I have no idea why this happens

For the second problem I thought to use `SVProgressHUD` to reload data but it doesn't work on `loadData()` function and if I try the Instance Method `tableView.reloadData()` it crashes.

variables are all `NSMutableArray` since that I have to load a lot of stuff that can change in the time

My `viewDidLoad()` function is very easy as you can see:

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        loadData()
    }
```

This is my Table view data source in our `Car_TableView.swift`:

```
override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return populateTable.count
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        return populateTable.count
    }


    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cellIdentifier = "carTableCell"

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellIdentifier) as! Car_Cell


        cell.carLabel?.text = "\(self.model[indexPath.row])"
        cell.carSubtitle?.text = "Year: \(self.year[indexPath.row]) - Price: \(self.price[indexPath.row])$"


        Alamofire.request("\(self.imagePathString[indexPath.row])").response { response in
            guard let image = UIImage(data:response.data!) else {
                // Handle error
                return
            }
            let imageData = image.jpegData(compressionQuality: 1.0)
            cell.carImage.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
            cell.carImage.image = UIImage(data : imageData!)
        }

        return cell
    }



    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == "ShowcarDetails" {

            let myIndexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow!

            //save detail page url in UserDefault
            let SVDetail = self.detailpage[myIndexPath.row]
            let SVDetaildefaults = UserDefaults.standard
            SVDetaildefaults.set(SVDetail, forKey: "sv_detail")
            SVDetaildefaults.synchronize()

            _ = segue.destination
                as! Car_Detail
        }
    }

    //SET CELLS SIZE
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        switch indexPath.row {
        case 0,1,2,3,4:
            return 100
        default:
            return 100
        }
    }
```

I also re-post the `loadData()` function because I simplified the operation in an only while statement:

```
func loadData() {
        //call data from database
        let rootRef = Database.database().reference()
        let conditionalRef = rootRef.child("Cars")
        conditionalRef.observe(.value) {(snap: DataSnapshot) in
            // Get all the children from snapshot you got back from Firebase
            let snapshotChildren = snap.children
            // Loop over all children (code) in Firebase
            while let child = snapshotChildren.nextObject() as? DataSnapshot {
                // Get code node key and save it to cars array
                self. populateTable.append(child.key)

                    let userRef = rootRef.child("Cars").child("\(child.key)")

                    userRef.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in
                        let userDict = snapshot.value as! [String: Any]

                            let address1 = userDict["Address"] as! String
                            self.address.add(address1)

                            let detail1 = userDict["Detail"] as! String
                            self.detailpage.add(detail1)

                            let carnumberOfRooms1 = userDict["numberOfRooms"] as! String
                            self.numberOfRooms.add(carnumberOfRooms1)

                            let carPrice1 = userDict["Price"]  as! String
                            self.price.add(carPrice1)

                            let carimageURL1 = userDict["imageURL"]  as! String
                            self.imagePathString.add(carimageURL1)
                    }) //end observeSingleEvent

            } //end while



            } //end snap

      }//end func
```

Comment: You are creating a new viewcontroller in every iteration in your while loop. Assuming you do the same when you present this controller, for sure that array will be empty.

Comment: you are right. Now I fixed that

Comment: Your last edit probably wont fix your problem. Now you will allocate a new vc in the move() function that you will actually never use. it will be deallocated at the end of the function scope.

As you are using segues, you need to set the cars array in prepare for segue method

Comment: there are news about this problem. See edits

Comment: I also tried to use "tableView.reloadData()" in the end of the snap brachets, but it don't works

Comment: Where do you call loadData() of your Car_TableView.swift? (sidenote: using those underlines is against the coding standard btw ...)

Comment: It’s on viewDidLoad override function. I need to load all the dynamic childs since the number of child is unknown because it is designed to be updated

Comment: I recommend that you edit your code that is being used and add relevant parts, such as the tableview datasource methods. This has apparently changed too much from the original question where you clearly had an issue of different instances being used and the scope of your data variables.

Comment: Thank you for your recommendation, I have edited the question as you had suggest.